# Apex Soql - Map Syntax

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I am trying to do this:

```
Map<Id,Id> reqMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
reqMap = [Select Id, TeamId from SObject];
```

Id and team Id are both of type Id. I don't want the entire SObject, just those two fields. I would like my map to look like:

```
{Id = xyz, TeamId =abc}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit unclear. `{Id = xyz, TeamId =abc}` is not a `Map<Id,Id>`. Your keys are strings (fieldnames), not Ids.

**If you need generic way to access all fields as key => value** - you can already do it with sObject class `get` methods. Or use `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`. Read up about [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) class (common base for all Account, Contact, Opportunity, MyCustomObject__c...).

```apex
Contact c = [SELECT Id, AccountId, LastName, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

System.debug(c.AccountId); // "normal" access

System.debug(c.get('AccountId')); // map-like access
System.debug(c.get('Email'));

// or loop through them all
Map<String, Object> myMap = c.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
for(String key : myMap.keyset()){
    System.debug(key + ' -> ' + myMap.get(key));
}
```

**If you really need a Map<Id, Id> where key is `Id` and value is `TeamId`**...

Typically you can put whole objects into the map (simple, quick, 1-liner operation without a loop; and you never know if you won't need more fields accessed by that Id so why not)

```apex
Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 10]);
for(Id i : contacts.keyset()){
    System.debug(i + ' -> ' + contacts.get(i).AccountId);
}
```

Or really make it `Map<Id, Id>` but then you need to loop over them:

```apex
Map<Id, Id> contactToAccount = new Map<Id, Id>();
for(Contact c: [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 10]){
    contactToAccount.put(c.Id, c.AccountId);
}
System.debug(contactToAccount);
```